# Why does a subsequent "has" step, make a Gremlin query significantly slower?

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I am trying to understand understand how gremlin queries work, especially when it comes to "AND" like queries.

When I execute the following query, it produces results in approximately 17 seconds.

```
g.V().has(id, gte(51200)).has(id, lte(51200000)).count().profile()
```

However, if I append another has statement to this such as the following, it doesn't even finish evaluating in 5 minutes.

```
g.V().has(id, gte(51200)).has(id, lte(51200000)).has('entity_type', 'Human').count().profile()
```

My expectation was that the added "has" step would only be executed on traversals that pass through the first two has steps. Therefore, I didn't expect this last has statement to add much time to the overall query, since it would simply be checking the value of a property.

My back end is a JanusGraph, configured with ElasticSearch and Google BigTable. It's got about 5 million vertices loaded.

Any guidance on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It is going to depend on how the graph engine optimizes the query and how much support an index can give. When using JanusGraph, assuming you have created the relevant indices,  a `.profile()` should show you how much the index is helping and where the time is being spent.

Answer (score 0):

You post is missing information about your indexes. Thus, I will make some assumptions.

**Assumption 1**: *`id` is indexed with a mixed-index and `entity_type` is not indexed.*

In this situation your last `has` step (`has('entity_type', 'Human')`) will require fetching properties for each of the retrieved vertex from your index. Currently, Graph indexes retrieve vertex/edge id only (*inline index properties retrieval is WIP but not part of JanusGraph 1.0.0*). Thus, any other `has` steps after the `has` steps covered by your index will need to fetch data from the database (fetch properties).

Before JanusGraph 1.0.0 `has` step which is outside of the index scope couldn't be optimized with multi-query (batch-query) optimization in your case.

Starting from JanusGraph 1.0.0 `has` step can not leverage multi-query optimization which should significantly speedup your second gremlin query. However, it will still be slower than the first query due to additional data fetching.

**Assumption 2**: *both `id` and `entity_type` are indexed but with two different indexes (i.e. they are not part of the same index).*

In this situation you may end up executing cross-index query (i.e. fetch data from both indexes and filter the final result in-memory) which in many cases is much worse then executing a single index and filter it by properties in-memory.

A good solution to this problem is cose-based index selection which will select a single most suited index as your `GraphIndex`. This work is also WIP and not part of JanusGraph 1.0.0, but you may track progress here: https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/pull/3246

If that's your case I suggest injecting a `limit` step after `has` steps covered by your desired index which will force executing only a single GraphIndex for your query. In other words, you can modify your query like below which should speedup your query execution (it will perform same as in `Assumption 1` in this case):

```
g.V().has(id, gte(51200)).has(id, lte(51200000)).limit(Long.MAX_VALUE).has('entity_type', 'Human').count().profile()
```